# How to put DB config outside .war?

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, connection, war

I have a small web service, currently all DB config(hostname/port/username/pw) is inside a class in the project.
When I export a .war file, it works fine. But what If I have to change my database?
should I change my sourc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Data Source in the target server and access DS through JNDI in your application code. In this way you can change the DB details whenever you want without changing the application code.